# Regex adding undesired line break between backreference and literal in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, line-breaks

I have a text file with a list of elements separated by line-breaks, like this:

```
alpha
beta
gamma
...
```

I want to get it into this format:

```
(alpha),
(beta),
(gamma),
...
```

So I am using following regular expressions in Notepad++ for replacing those lines:

```
Find: ([^\n]+)
Replace: \($1\),
```

but the output now strangely has another line-break for each line into it:

```
(alpha
),
(beta
),
(gamma
),
...
```

I have no clue how this is happening. When I solely use `$1` or `\),` apart for replacement it works just fine, but everytime I put a literal after the backreference it puts a line-break in between. I know that I can work around that with another regular expression afterwards, but could anybody explain to me why exactly this is happening?

Comment: It's probably `\r`, but I would suggest doing this instead: [`^(.*)$` replace with `($1),` and ensure `m` modifier is enabled](https://regex101.com/r/NmDw4r/1)

Comment: Instead of  `[^\n]` you should use `.` that only match any char other than line break chars. Only when you need to "exclude" some other char can you use something like `[^\r\n:]` (this will match any char but CR, LF and `:`)

Comment: Ahh yeah I just found out it's the `\r` I missed, silly me. Thank you for the info though.

Comment: I wasn't even aware that `.` would not match more than one line. What would I use if I wanted to match multiple lines then?

Comment: Typically you'd use `[\s\S]` to specify any whitespace or non-whitespace character (aka any character). Otherwise, you can use `.` and enable the `s` (single-line) modifier.

Comment: @StrikeAgainst notepad++ has a ". matches newline" option, which enables the `s` modifier.

Comment: @Lucas Trzesniewski Oh that's good to know, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `[^\n]` (=any char but an LF, line feed, `\n`) you should use `.` that only matches any char *other than line break chars*. Use the following regex to match a *non-empty* line:

```
^.+$
```

Replace with `\($0\)`, where `$0` replacement backreference (also called placeholder) stands for the whole match and the parentheses are escaped (since parentheses are special metacharacters inside Boost replacement patterns used to define conditional replacement patterns).

No need to use the `m` modifier here since `^` and `$` anchors match start and end of the *line* respectively *by default* in Notepad++.

See the NPP S&R settings:

[image]